# Multiuser GNU screen sessions

Tags: terminal

I am attempting to set up multi user screen sessions on Mac OS 10.7.3 and I run into the error `Attach attempt with invalid pid(xxx)!`.

If set it up as follows:

### Initial configuration of system:

Make the proper permisions for the screen command

```
sudo chmod u+s $(which screen)
sudo mkdir /var/run/screen/
sudo chmod 755 /var/run/screen/
```

### Screen setup

From `<user_sharing_screen>`

Initialize the screen with specified session name:

```
screen -S <session_name>
```

Make the screen multiuser:

```
C-a :multiuser on
C-a :acladd <user_to_share_with>
```

From `<user_to_share_with>` on the same system connect to the shared screen

```
screen -x <user_sharing_screen>/<session_name>
```

Then I get the error message `Attach attempt with invalid pid(xxx)!`

Comment: Are you using the stock 'screen'? If yes that would use /tmp/screens as temporary directory for the sessions?
This means you can skip the part with creating the /var/run/screen directory. Unfortunately I get the same error message when trying to connect.

Comment: Have you considered using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead of screen? Active development and you don't have to jump through all those hoops to get it working on OS X. iTerm even has built-in support for it.

Comment: I ended up just setting up a server with Ubuntu for everyone to login to.

Comment: A workaround could be trying tmux? They have very similar functionality. If you edit the criteria, I could answer in more detail if you are open to alternative software.

Answer (score 2):

[Update]The screen utility is broken according to a [superuser.com post](https://superuser.com/questions/117684/gnu-screen-multiuser-mode-is-broken-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard) starting from Mac OS X 10.6.

I was able to compile a working version of screen from [MacPorts.org](http://www.macports.org). If you're familiar with MacPorts I could provide you with an updated screen x86_64 binary or the source code patch file (changing one line in socket.c).[/Update]

**Update2** Add diff of socket.c

```
--- screen-4.0.3/socket.c   2003-09-08 16:26:50.000000000 +0200
+++ /Users/fluffy/screen-4.0.3/socket.c 2012-03-10 22:58:57.000000000 +0100
@@ -745,7 +745,7 @@
   if (eff_uid == real_uid)
     return kill(pid, 0);
   if (UserContext() > 0)
-    UserReturn(kill(pid, 0));
+    return 0;
   return UserStatus();
 }
```

Comment: I'm a homebrew user, is there anything comprable I could use?

Comment: You would have to create a brew formula for it. I haven't done one and frankly I don't see me having time for it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I created a homebrew fork with the patch shown above and it works for me.
To use it, do this:

```
brew tap stevemadere/homebrew-dupes && \
brew install stevemadere/dupes/screen && \
sudo chown root `which screen` && \
sudo chmod +s `which screen`
```